# "receive top X" doesn't return X messages

Tags: c#, ado.net, service-broker

I got a queue with a lot of messages.

I'm requesting 200 messages per read/transaction:

```
using (var connection = _configuration.ConnectionFactory.OpenConnection())
{
    using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.Transaction = transaction;
            command.CommandText = string.Format(ReadCommand, maxNumberOfMessagesPerRead, _queueName);
```

Generated SQL:

```
RECEIVE TOP(200) message_body, conversation_handle FROM [BenchQueue]
```

But I just get 100 messages per read. Are there a limit in SQL Server or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if you change 200 to something else, is it always 100 messages that are returned?

Comment: Anything larger than 100 will get me 100, anything less will give me less.

Comment: Stupid question, are there more than 100 messages in the queue?

Comment: 3 million messages :)

Comment: what happends if you run that query in another querier? Are you able to get more than 100 messages then?

Comment: BTW, you *must* always RECEIVE the `message_type_name`. You must have code in place to handle the system message types any dialog can received `http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog` and `http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error`. You must call `END DIALOG` to close the conversation properly when these message types are received.

Comment: I just checked for null to detect end dialog (we never use it ourselves nor errors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RECEIVE` statement will only returns messages belonging to a single conversation group. This is explicitly done in order to simplify processing of correlated messages in multi-threaded environment (max_queue_readers > 1). See [Conversation Group Locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171615.aspx) for details.

Unless you did any explicit conversation group management, each individual conversation is a separate conversation group. So you probably only have 100 messages per conversation in your queue.